# How to reduce Android Virtual Device ram usage?

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, android-virtual-device, kvm

I'm running a Nexus 5 API 25 (7.0) x86 Image on Ubuntu with KVM. There's no problem with the performance and all, but it uses too much ram. Even when I've set it to 512MB RAM and 128MB Heap on the AVD settings inside Android Studio.

Should it really be using this much? I remember it only being roughly 1GB when I was running windows 10 with HAXM. My system kind of chokes/bottlenecks overtime when it ends up using almost 90% of my 8GB RAM while I'm coding in Android Studio and using Atom for PHP on the backend so it gets annoying.

I'd love to hear anyone's advice on how I can reduce its RAM usage, I won't mind if it gets a little slower.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it initially uses 1.5GB RAM on startup which I'm confused that it uses that much despite being set to 512MB RAM on the AVD settings

Answer (score 0):

so here are my settings 
I have set the avd's ram to 2048mb
and using haxm I have set max ram usage to 2048 MB (2gb)

here's what you can do:-

you should try installing haxm again and set the max ram to 2gb and close all the unnecessary apps and browser tabs 8gb is enough for an android studio without compromising the performance

see ss first one is running an only android studio
the second one shows app running on an avd max ram usage by the avd is 2gb
the third one shows the total usage/free ram

[image: avd running at 2048 RAM set to 2048mb via haxm]
[image: only android studio running] 
[image: i also have a 8gb ram]

Comment: Greetings good sir,

I'm actually using linux (ubuntu) right now so I'm not actually using HAXM since it only works on Windows. However, I have KVM installed which is, if what I think it is, the equivalent of HAXM but for linux?

Anyhow. My emulator sure is fast just as it is with HAXM, but unlike on windows, the RAM limit on the AVD settings does not work unlike yours which you have even provided screenshots which it roughly limits itself to 2GB.

Mine, on the other hand, uses 1.5GB right off the bat when the AVD runs even when I set the limit to 512MB.

Comment: I usually have some other apps running along with android studio so I'm bound to hit 90% RAM usage within an hour or two of coding. I just thought my machine wont choke with swappiness by hitting 90% if I can reduce the amount of RAM my emulator uses to somewhere around 512MB to 1024MB